# How do I boot from a grub menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I recently added another partition to my hardrive where ubuntu was installed to and afterwards when I booted ubuntu I got sent to the grub rescue> terminal. The fix for that was that I had to reinstall grub on the correct partition for ubuntu to boot again. So I followed all the instructions from ubuntu to fix it from the live cd here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202 .

After I was done doing that I rebooted and the grub> terminal is now there. I would usually see a list to choose from with my os but Im guessing I have to update grub when I reboot or load the menu list. The problem is I did a lot of research to figure out how to boot from grub> but I cannot find a way to do so.

It is not easy finding a tutorial for doing so and I am completley stuck. I would like to know an easy way to boot into my ubuntu from grub and making the booting as it was before I made the partition. Please any help would be greatly appreciated for I need to get on my ubuntu to start doing some work...

Comment: i think this should be moved to: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

That usually means that you mounted the wrong partition when you installed grub. Try following this guide: http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide (in case it's still down when you read this here is the google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide )

I prefer this guide because, among other things, if you mount the wrong partition you will get an error message when you get to the chroot step, so you'll know that something needs to be changed.

Comment: both sites are now gone

Answer (score 0):

I am not a terminal expert, so I developed some skills to circumnavigate the terminal. Make a live usb, Than install a new os (You can do this on the hd or sd card or whatsoever. This will ensure, that the os you want to recover will be found. Restart the computer and select from the grub menu the os you want to recover. Than open a terminal and do "sudo update-grub" followed by "sudo grub-install /dev/sda" (sometimes hda). Restart the computer and voila.