# Ubuntu 12.04 boot issue after removing Kubuntu and resizing partition

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit installed on my desktop PC, and it was working fine until a short while ago. I tried to reboot into Ubuntu after removing a Kubuntu installation from my PC and resizing my Ubuntu partition using my 11.10 live CD. When I rebooted, grub showed a black screen and said

> Error: no such partition
>   grub rescue >_

I booted into my live CD again, Ubuntu was still installed and all my data was still there. I still cannot boot into Ubuntu. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Kubuntu was still in control of GRUB. When you removed it, you also removed the files grub needed to boot. Fortunately this should be an easy fix.

Since you're already on a live CD, I think the easiest route is to chroot to your installation and run the grub installation scripts. Start by opening your Ubuntu installation (your root partition, which contains folders such as "etc", "usr", and "home") in a file browser in order to mount it.

Now open a terminal.

### Find the Mount Pount

In the terminal, type `mount` This will print out several lines. Look for one that mentions your ubuntu installation in `/media`. It will look something like:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/disk type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

In the example above, the device is `/dev/sda1` and the mount point is `/media/disk`. Make a note of this, because we will use this information later.

### Set up the Chroot

We need to setup the chroot. This means we will link some system folders from the LiveCD to your installed system. To do this, paste the following text into the terminal, but replace `/media/disk` with the mount point you found earlier:

```
for i in sys dev proc; do sudo mount --bind /$i /media/disk/$i; done
```

The above command runs the following three commands:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /media/disk/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /media/disk/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc /media/disk/proc
```

This binds /sys, /dev/ and /proc to the same folders on /media/disk. This means that /media/disk/dev/ is actually /dev/

Now we are ready to chroot. In the terminal type `chroot /media/disk`, where /media/disk is your mount point.

You should now see a root shell (the prompt should end in #). Any command executed here is restricted to your installed partition, and will (for the most part) operate as if you  were on your installed system.

### Fix the Bootloader

Now all we need to do install the bootloader. In the terminal, paste the following two lines:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

**Note:** This assumes that you only have one drive in your computer. If you have two, or if you are running from a LiveUSB drive, make sure you replace `/dev/sda` in the above command with the device from the "Find the Mount Point" section above. **Do not** include the number at the end of the device. For example, if the device for your partition is `/dev/sdb2`, then you should use `grub-install /dev/sdb`.

And that's it! If those commands complete without error, then reboot your computer.

Comment: This may be difficult for the OP...

Comment: I will be unable to update grub due to my internet situation, is that a problem?

Comment: @Sauron: update-grub is a script that scans your partitions and writes the grub configuration file to give you a boot menu. It doesn't download anything from the internet.

Comment: I tried your answer, I got as far as setting up chroot. When I entered the coomand, bash said "syntax error near unexpected token 'do'". What now?

Comment: @Sauron: You mistyped the command. Try copying the command and pasting it into the terminal (Ctrl+Shift+V will paste into the terminal, or you can right-click on the terminal and select 'Paste')

Comment: @undecim: I did not type the command, I copied it into gedit and put the mount point into it, then pasted it into the terminal.

Comment: @undecim:--I may have put the wrong thing into it as the mount point, though. I entered the whole line of text which the terminal gave me when I typed "mount", instead of just /media/disk.

Comment: @undecim: I'm still getting the same error, after inputing the command correctly.

Comment: @Sauron: Then run each of these commands instead:

    sudo mount --bind /dev/ /media/disk/dev/

    sudo mount --bind /sys/ /media/disk/sys/

    sudo mount --bind /proc/ /media/disk/proc/

Comment: @undecim: Okay, I will.

Comment: @undecim: The terminal just says /media/disk/dev, /media/disk/sys, and /media/disk/proc do not exist--which they don't. I also don't have the permission to create those files (and don't know enough bash to use sudo to do so).

Comment: @Sauron: They should. If they don't, then /media/disk is not the mount point.

Comment: @undecim: So I should use the line from typing "mount" as the mount point?

Comment: @undecim: Sorry I'm so uncomprehending, but I'm tired and frustrated at the moment.

Comment: @Sauron: Yes. The line you see from typing "mount" in the terminal which describes your installed system (which should be the only line which includes "/media") describes the mount point. You should also be able to see it in the /media folder.

Comment: I'll go try it then.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling grub from a live CD boot?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows and http://askubuntu.com/questions/45682/cannot-get-to-grub-after-addition-of-new-win7-drive-and-install-of-11-04?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please boot a live CD, and select to Try Ubuntu. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

pressing enter when prompted. When this finishes, run

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and use the default settings. At the end, it will give a link. Please tell us this link to help  diagnose.

Comment: I am asking this question on my laptop, not my desktop, which is out in my shop and out of my wifi's reach. I'll have to drag it into the house to do this, it'll be a bit before I can tell you what happens.

Comment: Actually, I have decided to try undecim's answer, so I'm not going to try your's unless his doesn't work.